# Quando usar o adjetivo antes do substantivo?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, substantivos, ordem-de-expressões

O mais usado no Português é o adjetivo vir depois do substantivo, em oposição ao Inglês onde o mais comum é que o adjetivo venha antes. Exemplo:

Português:

> O carro vermelho

Inglês:

> The red car

Entretanto, existem alguns casos em que colocamos o adjetivo antes do substantivo.

Exemplos:

> - Mas que lindo dia
> - Um forte abraço

Quando é correto/indicado escrever de tal forma? Existe alguma regra na gramática que define isso? Qual?

Comment: Esses exemplos também podem ser: dia lindo e abraço forte.

Comment: Math, não quer reconsiderar a resposta correta como sendo a do Jacinto? Ela é claramente mais completa e embasada.

Comment: @stafusa não tem nenhuma resposta do jacinto aqui, seria a do artefacto q vc diz?

Comment: Math, claro! Desculpe o engano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As respostas dadas até agora acertam um pouco ao lado. A principal característica da posição pré-nominal dos ajetivos em função atributiva é o facto de que, nessa posição, **o adjetivo tem sempre uma leitura não restritiva**. Baseei a minha resposta na *Gramática do Português* da *Gulbenkian* (2013). Recomendo a leitura do capítulo referente aos adjetivos (cap. 31); tive de deixar muito de lado, especialmente no que toca à classificação dos adjetivos. Esta gramática explica *leitura restritiva* desta forma (vol. II, pág. 1440):

> A leitura **restritiva** de um adjetivo denotativo está associada à forma como esse adjetivo, em função atributiva, contribui, num determinado contexto, para identificação da entidade (singular ou plural) referida pelo sintagma nominal que contém o adjetivo. Numa frase como *o vestido **vermelho** foi para a lavandaria*, o falante restringe a aplicação do predicado ‘ir para a lavandaria’ a um determinado vestido que ele e o seu interlocutor têm em mente e que se caracteriza por ser de cor vermelha; ou seja, o adjetivo restringe o conjunto de vestidos àqueles que são de cor vermelha, e o artigo definido permite que o ouvinte identifique o vestido com essas propriedades presente no contexto situacional ou discursivo.
>
> Quando a propriedade denotada pelo adjetivo se aplica a todas as entidades possíveis no contexto situacional ou discursivo, não sendo, portanto, essencial para a identificação do referente do sintagma nominal, estamos perante uma leitura **não restritiva**. Por exemplo, em *a **ruidosa** festa não deixava dormir os vizinhos*, o adjetivo não isola uma festa, que se caracteriza por ser ruidosa, entre outras mais silenciosas. Na mente dos interlocutores já claro de que festa se está a falar [].

Como refere a primeira frase da citação, o contraste só se aplica aos adjetivos **denotativos**, i.e., aqueles que «atuam sobre o sentido do nome modificado, expressando propriedades que incidem sobre aspetos variados da entidade representada por esse nome» (*idem*, pág. 1368). Os adjetivos **avaliativos** («que expressam uma avaliação subjetiva do falante acerca das entidades referidas pelo sintagma nominal que contém o adjetivo» (*idem*)) e os **intensionais** (que «exprimem juízos do falante sobre a maneira como o próprio nome modificado se aplica à entidade designada pelo sintagma nominal» (*idem*, pág. 1369), como *falso*, *mero* e *alegado*) têm sempre uma leitura não restritiva, independente da posição em que ocorrem. Consequentemente, o inverso, a afirmação de que em posição pós-nominal os adjetivos têm sempre uma leitura restritiva, não é verdade. No entanto, se restringirmos a análise aos adjetivos *denotativos*, então já o podemos afirmar, com uma ressalva (*idem*, pág. 1441, negrito meu):

> Em síntese, com adjetivos denotativos, a leitura restritiva ocorre com o adjetivos posposto ao nome, formando com ele numa unidade prosódica, enquanto a leitura não restritiva ocorre quando o adjetivo está anteposto ao nome **ou quando, em posição pós-nominal, forma uma unidade prosódica autónoma, em aposição**.

A parte realçada cobre casos como *os gatos, mamíferos, dependem da mãe até aos dois meses*, onde *mamíferos* não tem uma leitura restritiva, apesar de posposto (cf. a impossibilidade de **os gatos mamíferos dependem da mãe até aos dois anos*).

As restantes respostas não são contudo descabidas, porque, no contexto dos adjetivos denotativos (*idem*, pág. 1451):

> [Q]uando os falantes utilizam um adjetivo que não serve propósitos de identificação de entidades, pretendem realçar as propriedades denotadas por esse adjetivo, ganhando este uma carga afetiva ou avaliativa. Por essa razão, adjetivos que expressam propriedades objetivas não aceitam anteposição (cf. **um solteiro rapaz*, **um fluvial peixe*, [...]). Apenas os adjetivos sobre os quais possa recair uma apreciação subjetiva podem ser antepostos.

A propósito de **fluvial peixe*, repare-se que *fluvial* pertence um subtipo de adjetivos denonativos, denominados *adjetivos relacionais* (ou *pseudoadjetivos*), que não admitem a anteposição. Mas explicar esta classe cai fora do âmbito desta resposta. Para mais informação, veja-se a secção 31.2.2.2 da *Gramática do Português*.

No entanto, como sugere *Earthliŋ*, com outras classes de adjetivos, não faz sentido falar de *subjetivo vs. objetivo*. Os adjetivos avaliativos podem ocorrer nas duas posições e, por definição, expressam sempre uma avaliação subjetiva. E em relação aos adjetivos intensionais (*idem*, pág. 139):

> Os adjetivos intensionais ocorrem com função atributiva, em posição pré-nominal (cf. {*falso/mero/suposto/verdadeiro*} *advogado*), sem o efeito estilístico usual provocado pelos adjetivos qualificativos [subtipo dos denotativos] quando ocorrem nessa posição; por outras palavras, a posição pré-nominal é a sua posição normal, não marcada. Alguns deles (como *alegado*, *mero*, *suposto*) só podem mesmo ocorrer nessa posição.

Outros fatores que afetam a posição dos adjetivos:

- em «adjetivos que exprimem atitudes mentais e comportamentais e estiverem associados a nomes que denotam determinadas funções sociais, a anteposição permite a leitura absoluta do adjetivo, não disponível em posposição (comparem-se *a carinhosa professora* e *a professora carinhosa*, em que apenas o primeiro permite a interpretação de que a pessoa referida é carinhosa em geral e não apenas na sua qualidade de professora» (*idem*, pág. 1451);
- o ritmo ou a estrutura prosódica, os quais «podem favorecer [] a anteposição de adjetivos, especialmente quando há vários modificadores ou complementos do sintagma nominal: cf. ?*uma saia comprida de linho maravilhosa* vs. *uma maravilhosa saia comprida de linho*. Quando os sintagmas nominais são muito extensos, os falantes preferem a anteposição de adjetivos que possam receber uma leitura subjetiva, mesmo que não sejam avaliativos puros — cf. #*uma estudante de Física do Porto simpática* vs. *uma simpática estudante de Física do Porto*.» (*idem*, pág. 1452);
- fatores estilísticos; «quanto mais objetiva for a propriedade atribuída por um adjetivo, mais expressivo tem de ser o texto para que se possa conferir o valor afetivo associado à anteposição», especialmente se os nomes em causa denotarem seres vivos (*idem*, pág. 1453);
- desfazer ambiguidades entre adjetivos que podem pertencer a várias classes, nomeadamente entre:

  - leituras qualificativas e adverbiais; a anteposição favorece a leitura adverbial (compare-se *um amigo velho* e *um velho amigo*) (*idem*, pág. 1451);
  - leituras avaliativas e denotativas; a anteposição favorece uma leitura avaliativa (compare-se *um fantástico conto* com *um conto fantástico*; no primeiro caso, só a leitura avaliativa está disponível) (*idem*);
  - leituras qualificativas e relacionais, dois subtipos dos adjetivos denotativos; com a anteposição só a leitura qualificativa é possível (compare-se *a música popular* com *a popular música*) (*idem*, pg. 1452);
  - leituras intensionais ou modais e leituras denotativas; a posposição é preferível quando são denotativos e a preposição caso contrário (compare-se *amigos falsos* e *falsos amigos*) (*idem*).

Comment: Quando vi o primeiro *intensional*, pensei que fosse engano. Isso vem de quê? De *intenso*, não me parece.

Comment: @Jacinto Vem de [_intensão_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intension).

Comment: @Jacinto Vê [este artigo](http://revistas.iel.unicamp.br/index.php/cel/article/download/2878/4147). Acho que explica bem e sucintamente o assunto.

Comment: Eh pá, eu até fui ver *intensão* ao Aulete, mas ele não o tem. Também já tenho a gramática da Gulbenkian. Quando tiver tempo leio o capítulo.

Comment: @Jacinto [Tem sim](http://www.aulete.com.br/intens%C3%A3o), definição 4., remetendo para _compreensão_ (embora não explique a diferença entre _intensão_ e _compreensão_).

Comment: Enganei-me: foi *intensional* que eu procurei.

Comment: Esta deveria ser a reposta aceita.

Answer (score 12):

Tal como você disse, a posição normal do adjetivo na língua portuguesa é à direita do substantivo, no entanto há casos em que a posição usada, na colocação de adjetivos qualificativos, altera a forma como interpretamos a frase:

A sequência normal SUBSTANTIVO + ADJECTIVO dá a noção de que o adjectivo possui valor objectivo:

> noite escura
> dia triste
> rapaz bom
> campos verdes

enquanto que a sequência ADJECTIVO + SUBSTANTIVO dá a noção de que o adjectivo assume um valor subjectivo:

> escura noite
> triste dia
> bom rapaz
> verdes campos

ou assume um sentido figurado:

> um grande homem (grandeza figurada) / um homem grande (grandeza material)
> uma pobre mulher (uma mulher infeliz) / uma mulher pobre (uma mulher sem recursos)

Fonte: [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/colocacao-do-adjectivo-antes-ou-depois-do-substantivo/26245)

Answer (score 6):

Já tem uma reposta, que explica a distinção objetivo–subjetivo, que funciona bem como regra geral

- [subst] [adj] é "objetivo"
- [adj] [subst] é "subjetivo"

Mas têm alguns adjetivos em que nenhuma das opções seria considerada "subjetiva":

> **antigo**
> meu antigo rádio ↔ meu rádio antigo
> <sub>ambos são fatos "objetivos"</sub>
>
> **certa**
> uma certa reposta ↔ uma reposta certa
> <sub>aqui a ordem [subst] [adj] parece mais "subjetiva", não?</sub>
>
> **diferentes** (*pl.*)
> diferentes tipos ↔ tipos diferentes
>
> **único**
> uma única chance ↔ uma chance única
> <sub>a segunda opção, uma chance "especial", parece mais "subjetiva"</sub>
>
> <sub>Referência: Whitlam, *Modern Brazilian Portuguese Grammar*, pp. 39–40.</sub>

Comment: Entendo "uma certa resposta" como "uma determinada resposta"  ex:  Eu não gostei de uma certa resposta que ele me deu.  Eu já li todas as respostas, e tem uma certa resposta que me surpreendeu muito.   Já "uma resposta certa" é uma resposta correta.

Comment: Também vejo diferença no exemplo "antigo": "meu rádio antigo" = "meu rádio que é uma antiguidade"; "meu antigo rádio" = "rádio que foi meu".

Answer (score 0):

Caminho da Canoa Pequeno (Pequeno se refere ao caminho da canoa e não somente a Canoa), pode-se usar Pequeno Caminho da Canoa

Comment: Olá Maninaldo, minhas boas-vindas. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas você dá apenas um único exemplo, enquanto a pergunta claramente é: "Existe alguma regra na gramática"?, portanto tua postagem não é uma resposta.