# Múltiplos adjetivos

Tags: adjetivos, ordem-de-expressões

Em Português, os adjetivos objetivos são colocado depois os substantivos, como:

> o autocarro vermelho

Mas qual é o caso para múltiplos adjetivos? Por exemplo, em inglês nós escrevemos:

> the old, red car

ou

> the old, red, rusty car

Qual é a frase correta em português? Será que todos os adjetivos vêm depois do substantivo?

Comment: `frase` é do género feminino, também a forma de perguntar deverá ser `como é` e não `que é`: *Como é a frase correta em português?*

Answer (score 13):

Os adjetivos podem ser colocadas antes ou depois do substantivo.

Pegando no exemplo ***the old, red, rusty car*** todas estas formas são corretas:

> *o velho e enferrujado carro vermelho.*
>   *o velho carro vermelho e enferrujado.*
>   *o carro vermelho, velho e enferrujado.*

No entanto há formas que, ou não se aplicam, soam mal, ou poderão ter significado distinto:

> *o vermelho carro, velho e enferrujado.*

Isso tem a ver com o facto de alguns adjetivos adquirirem significado subjetivo ou figurado, quando colocados [antes do substantivo](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/144/122):

> *uma boa mulher(de carácter) / uma mulher boa(fisicamente)*
>   *um grande homem (grandeza figurada) / um homem grande (grandeza material)*

Comment: A última parte da resposta contradiz a primeira frase, não?

Comment: @E_net4 tem razão. Vou reformular a resposta.

Comment: @ramaral "o vermelho carro" é correto?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não soa bem, mas não sei dizer se é correto ou não. Coloquei a frase para introduzir o tema do significado subjetivo ou figurado dos adjectivos quando colocados antes do substantivo. O que acontece é que neste caso não encontramos nenhum significado figurado para vermelho quando associado a carro.

Answer (score 9):

> Em Português, os adjetivos objectivos são colocado depois os
> substantivos (...)

É a posição mais frequente -- quase a única na escrita técnica --, mas nem sempre ficam nesse lugar, especialmente na linguagem poética.

Ver, por exemplo, a questão [Quando usar o adjetivo antes do substantivo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/144/quando-usar-o-adjetivo-antes-do-substantivo) e suas respostas ([1](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/227/105) e [2](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/406/105)).

No caso de dois adjectivos, estes ligam-se habitualmente pela conjunção "e". Podem ser colocados os dois ou apenas um antes do substantivo.

Exemplo: "*triste* e *leda madrugada*", do [célebre soneto de Luís de Camões *Aquela triste e leda madrugada*](http://aviagemdosargonautas.net/2014/06/10/aquela-triste-e-leda-madrugada-um-soneto-de-luis-de-camoes/):

> Aquela triste e leda madrugada,
>
> chea toda de mágoa e de piedade,
>
> emquanto houver no mundo saudade
>
> quero que seja sempre celebrada.

Outro exemplo: "a *bela* jovem *alegre* e *extrovertida* aceitou o convite dele".