# Adjetivos "grande" e "pequeno" ficam antes ou depois do substantivo?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, sintaxe, adjetivos, ordem-de-expressões

Eu vi dois exemplos como os seguintes, nos quais os adjetivos *grande* e *pequeno* são usado:

> Cachorro grande.
>
> O pequeno cachorro branco está brincando com uma bola amarela no jardim.

Minha pergunta é: posso falar:

> Grande cachorro.
>
> O cachorro pequeno branco está brincando com uma bola amarela no jardim.

Comment: Majid, vê também a pergunta [Quando usar o adjetivo antes do substantivo](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/144/quando-usar-o-adjetivo-antes-do-substantivo/406#406)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quando usar o adjetivo antes do substantivo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/144/quando-usar-o-adjetivo-antes-do-substantivo)

Comment: Na pergunta linkada, entre a resposta do Ramaral e a do Artefacto é possível encontrar a resposta a esta pergunta. Mas a nota do Ramaral sobre o uso de *grande* é muito breve, e a resposta do Artefacto é para iniciados, não é para principiantes. Portanto, acho que se deve manter aberta esta pergunta.

Comment: Seis dias depois, estou agora firmemente convencido que esta pergunta não é uma duplicata. Só um exemplo: nas respostas à outra pergunta há uma única nota especificamente acerca de *grande*:  "um grande homem (grandeza figurada) / um homem grande (grandeza material)" (resposta do Ramaral). Ora isto não explica satisfatoriamente a diferença entre *grande cachorro* e *cachorro grande* (em que consiste a grandeza figurada do homem? aplica-se ao cachorro?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pequeno

Vou deixar o *branco* de fora para simplificar. Dizes:

- ***O cachorro pequeno*** para o distinguires de outros cachorros que são maiores. Por exemplo, estão dois cachorros no jardim, e um é maior que o outro. Então tu dizes *o cachorro pequeno* para eu saber de qual cachorro estás a falar. é uma forma neutra e desapaixonada de falar.
- ***O pequeno cachorro*** para realçar que o cachorro é pequeno e exprimir um certo afeto; é um pouco como dizer “o cachorrinho” (mas *cachorrinho* é mais afetuoso que *pequeno cachorro*). Até podem lá estar outros cachorros ainda mais pequenos. Mas se eu souber qual é o cachorro de que estás a falar (por exemplo, eu estou lá, e tu simplesmente apontas para o cachorro), tu podes dizer *o pequeno cachorro* simplesmente para realçar que o cachorro é pequeno e exprimir afeto.

Voltando a pôr o *branco*. *O cachorro pequeno branco* — para distinguir esse cachorro de outros que também são pequenos mas não são brancos. *O cachorro branco pequeno*  — para distinguir de outros cachorros brancos que são maiores. *O pequeno cachorro branco* — não é preciso distinguir de cachorros maiores, mas tu queres salientar que ele é pequeno.

### Grande

O que eu disse acerca de *pequeno* também se aplica a *grande*. Mas há mais:

- ***O cachorro grande***. Aqui, depois do nome, *grande* refere-se sempre ao tamanho.
- ***O grande cachorro***. Aqui, antes do nome, *grande* quer dizer que, na tua opinião, o cachorro tem qualidades excelentes e merece a nossa admiração e respeito.

Como o significado de *grande* muda antes do nome, até podes dizer coisas como:

> O grande pequeno cachorro protegeu a dona dos assaltantes.

Isto significa que o cachorro tem tamanho pequeno, mas é um grande cachorro: corajoso, não teve medo dos assaltantes.

E aqui está um exemplo real de um [“**pequeno grande cachorro**” que salvou quatro gatinhos de um incêndio.](http://lili-gata.blogspot.com/2011/09/cao-heroi-salva-gatinhos-de-incendio.html).

### E se não for *cachorro?*

A seguir ao nome, *pequeno* e *grande* referem-se sempre ao tamanho (pelo menos não me lembro de exceções). Mas antes do nome, o significado varia. Vou só dar exemplos.

*Grande* significa ’admirável’, como com *cachorro*, com pessoas ou coisas que possam suscitar a nossa admiração: *grande homem, mulher, cantor, filme, país, descoberta*, etc.

Com outras coisas, *grande*, tal como *pequeno*, pode também referir-se ao tamanho: *grande/pequeno asteroide, lago, praça, tubarão*, etc. Mantém-se a diferença que depois do nome é uma forma neutra e desapaixonada de falar e distingue de outros maiores ou menores, enquanto antes do nome exprime afeto ou que a coisa nos impressiona de alguma maneira.

Mas *grande ofensa* é uma ofensa grave; *grande problema* é um problema difícil; é análogo com *pequeno* : *pequeno (pouco difícil) problema, pequena (pouco grave) ofensa*; semelhantemente com *crime, infração*. Com estas palavras, *pequeno* e *grande* geralmente não vêm depois do nome.

*Grande comerciante* pode ser ’admirável’ ou pode ter um negócio grande. ***Um** pequeno comerciante* significa simplesmente que tem um negócio pequeno, mas ***o** pequeno comerciante* é normalmente uma criança ou adolescente. É o mesmo com *grande/pequeno empresário, agricultor, fazendeiro*.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto faz.

Geralmente quando se quer dar um tom poético ou de maior formalidade coloca-se o adjetivo na frente do substantivo, mas isso não é uma regra. Na linguagem informal geralmente usa-se o adjetivo depois do substantivo.