# Está correto usar o adjetivo antes do substantivo na frase "Há uma grande casa..."

Tags: gramática, substantivos, adjetivos

Porque no caso *"Há uma pequena casa"* o adjetivo está antes do substantivo?

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Como a versão geral dessa pergunta já foi feita, faço o redirecionamento em pouco — mas posso dizer que, sim, esta frase em particular está correta.

Comment: @stafusa, a pergunta [Adjetivos "grande" e "pequeno" ficam antes ou depois do substantivo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6175/adjetivos-grande-e-pequeno-ficam-antes-ou-depois-do-substantivo) é talvez ainda mais relevante.

Comment: Obrigado, @Jacinto

Answer (score 2):

Embora não seja o mais comum na língua portuguesa, usar o adjetivo antes do substantivo é gramaticalmente correto.  Do ponto de vista semântico, esse tipo de construção tenta dar ênfase à qualidade em questão.

- Havia uma grande casa na esquina.
- Uma terrível dúvida me assolava.
- Foi uma estranha ocorrência.

Contudo, nem todos os adjetivos se prestam a isso e o resultado não é idiomático.  Por exemplo:

- Ele contou-nos uma engraçada história.
- Substitua as sublinhadas palavras por seus respectivos sinônimos.
- Mandei lavar a suja roupa.

Esses últimos exemplos soam muito estranhos a um ouvido nativo.

Comment: Pois, de vez em quando o português prega-nos estas rasteiras. Como quando descobri que "cu" e "nu" não levam acento, fiquei bem confuso.