# Mudança de significado variando a posição do adjetivo?

Tags: significado, substantivos, adjetivos

Supondo que eu quero dizer que o grupo é pequeno em termos de quantidade de pessoas na seguinte frase

> A nossa história data a 2017 com um grupo pequeno.

É bastante comum ouvir que «grande homem» ou «homem grande» não significam a mesma coisa e nesse caso dá para visualizar que o segundo refere-se às características físicas do homem. Pela mesma lógica, usei «grupo pequeno». No entanto, neste caso específico («pequeno grupo» e «grupo pequeno») não vejo a diferença no significado.

Comment: Já existe [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6175/adjetivos-grande-e-pequeno-ficam-antes-ou-depois-do-substantivo) especificamente sobre *pequeno* e *grande*, e [esta outra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/144/quando-usar-o-adjetivo-antes-do-substantivo?noredirect=1&lq=1) mais geral. É possível que elas já respondam à tua pergunta.

Comment: A segunda já conhecia. A primeira sim, parece ser igual @Jacinto

Comment: Então eu sugeria que fizesses uma de duas coisas. Se com as respostas às outras perguntas já ficas com a tua dúvida cabalmente esclarecida, podes fechar a tua pergunta como duplicata. Se ainda há algum aspeto que gostarias de ver mais esclarecido, podes editar a tua pergunta focando o tal aspeto.

Comment: Já agora, no teu exemplo eu diria "pequeno grupo". Nem estou a derivar isto de regra nenhuma; é simplesmente o que me soa melhor, intuitivamente.